# I am getting the "no module named pandas:" error after pandas being installed

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove duplicates from a CSV file with the following script:

```
import pandas as pd

toclean = pd.read_csv('LCG.csv')

deduped = toclean.drop_duplicates([col1,col2])
deduped.to_csv('LCGc.csv')
```

But I am getting the error "no module named pandas". However I have already installed pandas via miniconda.

[image: conda list shows pandas is installed]

Comment: How many python versions were installed in your system? And which python did you use to run the script?

Comment: can you run the pip3 freeze command to see if it actually installed properly?

Comment: Probably you have multiple versions of Python installed.

Comment: Pandas may be installed on your Conda but is it installed in the environment you've activated?

Comment: @Achilles I have recently discovered I have multiple Versions of python installed. How do I set the one I want to use to my IDLE?

Comment: @shja If you don't use no other versions of python ,then why don't you uninstall them all clean and reinstall the version you use ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have multiple versions of Python and the one currently using is python 2.7 so in order to install pandas on that specific version ,try this :

```
pip27 install pandas
```